# Как сделать словарь из списков

Tags: python, list, словарь

У меня есть список с ключами и список со значениями
ключи:

```py
k = [3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6] 
 z = [
     [3, [[2, 4], [0, 6], [2, 2]]],
     [2, [[1, 4], [8, 7]]],
     [3, [[0, 3], [7, 6], [8, 3]]],
     [3, [[4, 2], [1, 1], [7, 7]]],
     [2, [[6, 4], [7, 0]]],
     [1, [[6, 6]]]]
     [1, [[4, 9]]
]
```

Мне нужно создать цикл, который бы делал словарь для элементов, чтобы было так:

`{k[0]:z[0], k[1]:z[1]...}`и тд до конца

Пыталась через цикл `for`, но мне он делает несколько словарей, а мне нужен один большой. Помогите пожалуйста!

Также нужно, чтоб каждое ключ-значение было на новой строчке, через `width = 1` не работает.

Comment: а ничего, что k и z разной длины?

Comment: Случайно не скопировала последний элемент. Теперь их поровну

Comment: dict(zip(z, k))

Comment: "Пыталась через цикл фор, но мне он делает несколько словарей, а мне нужен один большой."  код в студию

Comment: по-русски list - это "список". не лист, а список.

Answer (score 1):

```py
k = [3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6]
z = [
     [3, [[2, 4], [0, 6], [2, 2]]],
     [2, [[1, 4], [8, 7]]],
     [3, [[0, 3], [7, 6], [8, 3]]],
     [3, [[4, 2], [1, 1], [7, 7]]],
     [2, [[6, 4], [7, 0]]],
     [1, [[6, 6]]],
     [1, [[4, 9]]]
]

dict(zip(k,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю такой код будет правильным:

```py
k = [3, 1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 6]
z = [
     [3, [[2, 4], [0, 6], [2, 2]]],
     [2, [[1, 4], [8, 7]]],
     [3, [[0, 3], [7, 6], [8, 3]]],
     [3, [[4, 2], [1, 1], [7, 7]]],
     [2, [[6, 4], [7, 0]]],
     [1, [[6, 6]]],
     [1, [[4, 9]]]
]

result = {}

for index in range(len(k) - 1):
    result[k[index]] = z[index]
```

PS: Я поправил список `z`, потому-что он был не правильно построен. Выходила `IndentationError`

PSS: У меня цикл `for` работает, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос.